# How to repair dimmed image of book page

Tags: c#, image-processing

I have 1000 Image of book page, Its text is dimmed as this piece
[image: Dimmed Text]

Now I tried to repair it to be more clearly to read, I use this code

```
 private Bitmap repairImage(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        Color cc=Color.FromArgb(255, 251, 251, 251);
        for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; y++)
            {
                if (bmp.GetPixel(x, y).R>238)
                {
                    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White);
                }
                else
                {
                    bmp.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
                }
            }
        }
       return bmp;
    }
```

Due to the image dimensions is 1168 x 1807 it took a lot of time to finish repair, it exactly loops 2110576 cycles.
Is there any another way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020406/travel-through-pixels-in-bmp (avoid using GetPixel() and SetPixel() for every pixel)

Comment: Look up gamma and ColorMatrix! See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865511/contrast-with-color-matrix/23866677?s=1|6.2068#23866677), especially the link to the guide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I can think of it to use the built-in [`ColorMatrix`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix(v=vs.90).aspx) class to change the **Gamma** and the **Contrast** of the image.

Here is a result for a `Gamma = 6.27` and a `Contrast = +1.04`:

[image]

Here is the code I used:

```
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
..

public static Bitmap ApplyGamma(Bitmap bmp0, float gamma, float contrast)
{

    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(bmp0.Width, bmp0.Height);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp1))
    {
        ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix(new float[][] 
                {
                    new float[] {contrast, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                    new float[] {0,contrast, 0, 0, 0},
                    new float[] {0, 0, contrast, 0, 0},
                    new float[] {0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                    new float[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}
                });


        ImageAttributes attributes = new ImageAttributes();
        attributes.SetColorMatrix(colorMatrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default,
                                               ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
        attributes.SetGamma(gamma, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
        g.DrawImage(bmp0, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp0.Width, bmp0.Height),
                    0, 0, bmp0.Width, bmp0.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);
    }
    return bmp1;
}
```

The function uses two variables and two `TrackBars` along with two `Labels`:

```
float gamma = 1f ;
float contrast = 1f;

private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gamma = 1f * trackBar1.Value / 100f;
    label1.Text = gamma.ToString("#0.00");
    pictureBox1.Image = ApplyGamma(originalImage, gamma, contrast);
}


private void trackBar2_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    contrast = 1f * trackBar2.Value / 1000f;
    label2.Text = contrast.ToString("#0.00");
    pictureBox1.Image = ApplyGamma(originalImage, gamma, contrast);
}
```

Note that I am **leaking** the Bitmaps; it is just for testing ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I use this **(C++)** code:

```
void picture::enhance_range()
    {
    int i,x,y,a0[4],min[4],max,n,c0,c1,q,c;
    if (xs<1) return;
    if (ys<1) return;

    n=0;    // dimensions to interpolate
    if (pf==_pf_s   ) { n=1; c0=0; c1=127*3; }
    if (pf==_pf_u   ) { n=1; c0=0; c1=255*3; }
    if (pf==_pf_ss  ) { n=2; c0=0; c1=32767; }
    if (pf==_pf_uu  ) { n=2; c0=0; c1=65535; }
    if (pf==_pf_rgba) { n=4; c0=0; c1=  255; } // this is your image pixel format so ignore the other pf statements

    // find min,max intensities
    dec_color(a0,p[0][0],pf);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++) min[i]=a0[i]; max=0;
    for (y=0;y<ys;y++)
     for (x=0;x<xs;x++)
        {
        dec_color(a0,p[y][x],pf); // this just unpack pixel color p[][] to a0[4]={r,g,b,a}
        for (q=0,i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
            c=a0[i]; if (c<0) c=-c;
            if (min[i]>c) min[i]=c;
            if (max<c) max=c;
            }
        }
    // change dynamic range to max
    for (y=0;y<ys;y++)
     for (x=0;x<xs;x++)
        {
        dec_color(a0,p[y][x],pf);
        for (i=0;i<n;i++) a0[i]=c0+(((a0[i]-min[i])*(c1-c0))/(max-min[i]+1));
//      for (i=0;i<n;i++) if (a0[i]<c0) a0[i]=c0; // clamp if needed
//      for (i=0;i<n;i++) if (a0[i]>c1) a0[i]=c1; // clamp if needed
        enc_color(a0,p[y][x],pf); // this just pack a0[4]={r,g,b,a} to pixel color p[][]
        }
    }
```

where:

- `pf` is current pixel format in your case `pf=_pf_rgba` which is just enum constant
- `xs,ys` is resolution of image
- `p[y][x]` is direct pixel access to image
- `enc_color,dec_color` just pack/unpack color components for desired pixel format

This is the result:

[image: example]

The main idea is to find minimal and maximal color value, Then enhance this dynamic range to maximum. For example (on grayscale colors) your image has:

```
min=181;
max=254;
```

So if you take each pixel and rescale to max `<0,255>` you need to do something like:

```
color=(color-min)*255/(max-min);
```

for each pixel of the image and that is all.

**[Notes]**

As @RosaGronchi mentioned Your current approach is slow due to use of `getpixel,setpixel` use scanlines instead (that should be few thousand times faster).

- see [GDI Bitmap and `ScanLine[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699076/2521214)

Also Another disadvantage of your approach is that you just binarise the image loosing all rendered anti-aliasing of text ...

Comment: _that should be few thousand times faster_ That sounds rather optimistic to me.

Comment: @TaW not at all if coded right ... each `setpixel` or `getpixel` invokes **many** GDI calls checking for bouns,pixelformat,coverions and much more... The `ScanLine` property does it too but only once per line and if remembered then only once per line per image/resize and can be accessed repeatedly after ... on heavy pixel access the usual speed boost is around `10000x` times (on for example SW 3D rendering or fill algorithms) ... but have to be coded right ...

Comment: Well the last time I compres Lockbits and get/setPixel is was aound 20 times faster. A lot but  by no means thousands.. But that is not the same as your code, I guess..

Comment: @Taw It depends on how much you actually use the `getpiel`,`setpixel` instead of  direct pixel access ...  opposed to the amount of alternative GDI calls. If the `getpixel`,`setpixel` you are referring to are not GDI then it is whole another topic.

Comment: I compared using GDI+ Get/SetPixel from C# angainst LockBits.

Comment: @TaW the LockBits does copying the memory or not? If yes that would explain small speed boost....

Comment: In the center of a LockBits routine there are two  [Marshall.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) calls, so yes memory gets copied. But do not know if nothing is copied with a ColorMatrix, though.