# What does MSPaint process to eliminate objects in background when PNG image is converted to 4-bit BMP image?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, image-processing, bitmap

I opened a PNG image, clicked `Save As`, changed to `16 color Bitmap`, and saved it.
Then, MSPaint warned about loss of information about transparent and image qualities and, I clicked `OK`.

As a result, letters behind the black glass object disappeared clearly like [this image (Before->After)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFToz.png).

By changing `PixelFormat` or removing transparent area on C# (.Net 4.6.2), I tried to implement this feature just like MSPaint, however, it wasn't removed clearly. In some way, Nothing changed.

Is that not about `PixelFormat` or ColorDepth?
Or, Is there a way to get rid of objects behind another on PNG?

What should I do to implement that?

**EDIT 1**

Thank you so much, @TaW. By following [your method `ApplyGamma`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34121073/4131847), I could solve the issue.

Comment: [Color quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization)

Comment: No, this is not coming (directly) from the reduced pixelformaz. You may want to play with contrast and gamma, best using a ColorMatrix! [Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+ColorMatrix). Maybe best fit: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116706/how-to-repair-dimmed-image-of-book-page/34121073?r=SearchResults&s=10|18.5978#34121073)

Comment: Fairly sure this is just the result of matching the colours to the more limited 16 colour palette. It most likely uses the standard Windows 16 colour palette, and there is no very dark gray on that, so the closest colour it finds is black. But yea, serious colour degradation is not the way to solve issues like this.